# Can setClipBounds be called on a view before it has been drawn?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am building a custom compound control. One of the components of this compound control is a customized button. My ShiftingTabButton is a nested class in my compound control class.

I need to set the ShiftingTabButton's clipBounds to be slightly shorter than the actual height when it is first drawn.

In the ShiftingTabButton's constructor shown below, I set up a few of the necessary parameters and then call **`measure()`** with mode **`UNSPECIFIED`**, to determine the intended size of the new view. When I run this in debug mode, I can see **`width`** = 160 and **`height`** = 64 for my Nexus 7.

All good so far.

But when I try to call setClipBounds() with my revised clipBounds, the app crashes.

I've tried defining a **`useShorterClipBounds`** flag in the constructor, moved the setting of the **`clipBounds`** to the **`onDraw()`** method and made it dependent on a flag check, but I still get the same crash.

```
public ShiftingTabButton(Context context, String string) {
    super(context);

    // parameter setup
    this.setText(string);
    this.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_unselected));
    this.setId(generateChildViewId());
    this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
    this.setPadding(dpToPx(7), 0, dpToPx(7), 0);

    // measure the view     
    int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    this.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = this.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = this.getMeasuredHeight();

    // adjust the clipBounds        
    Rect clipBounds = new Rect();
    clipBounds.set(0, 0, width, height - dpToPx(16));
    this.setClipBounds(clipBounds); // !App crashes executing this line of code!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered that setClipBounds() was only added to the sdk in Version 4.3 r2.1 while the Nexus 7 is running 4.2.2, so the method could not be found.

Instead, the clipping should be done directly on the canvas in the onDraw() method.

Answer (score 8):

You can as easily just copy the implementation to support older versions:

```
private Rect mClipBounds;

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Clip bounds implementation for JB_MR1 and older
    // Does not save the canvas, because the View implementation also doesn't...
    if (mClipBounds != null) {
        canvas.clipRect(mClipBounds);
    }
    super.draw(canvas);
}

@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public void setClipBounds(Rect clipBounds) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        super.setClipBounds(clipBounds);
        return;
    }

    if (clipBounds != null) {
        if (clipBounds.equals(mClipBounds)) {
            return;
        }
        if (mClipBounds == null) {
            invalidate();
            mClipBounds = new Rect(clipBounds);
        } else {
            invalidate(Math.min(mClipBounds.left, clipBounds.left),
                    Math.min(mClipBounds.top, clipBounds.top),
                    Math.max(mClipBounds.right, clipBounds.right),
                    Math.max(mClipBounds.bottom, clipBounds.bottom));
            mClipBounds.set(clipBounds);
        }
    } else {
        if (mClipBounds != null) {
            invalidate();
            mClipBounds = null;
        }
    }
}

@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public Rect getClipBounds() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        return super.getClipBounds();
    } else {
        return (mClipBounds != null) ? new Rect(mClipBounds) : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point... grab the implementation of the new method from the source code. I like it.